# Firebase cloud functions query for large dataset

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a large dataset on firebase which needs to download on certain real-time database trigger. Instead of downloading all data in one shot I would like to download it in chunk using firebase query. I tried something like

```
admin.database().ref(bucket).orderByKey().endAt("\uf8ffaa")
```

Here I would like to download all data whose key end with the character 'aa' but it's downloading the entire snapshot.

Firebase Structure:

```
{
  "0":{
    "58f613052c7d6ab48bbb614b34e78c3e":{
      "no1":{
        "c":"1"
      },
      "no2":{
        "c":"1"
      }
    },
    "58f613052c7d6ab48bbb614b34e78caa":{
      "no1":{
        "c":"1"
      },
      "no3":{
        "c":"1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Node '0' contains huge data so suppose I want to download all data from '0' node which has key's ending with the character 'aa'.

Comment: Can you add your sample database structure?

Comment: It's not possible to do a query for values that end with something as far as I know. `endAt()` only sets the end point for your query, it's in the name: end**At**, not end**With** :)

Comment: @AndréKool any other workaround? using limitToFirst() or something else.

Comment: If you want to read it in chunks you might want to look at questions about pagination for idea's